# How to downgrade a PPA package (Firefox ESR 60 to ESR 52)?

Tags: package-management, firefox, dpkg, ppa

I am trying to downgrade firefox-esr from 60 to [52](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/15071265) from `ppa:mozillateam/ppa`.

PPA only has the latest version so apt-get can't downgrade the package. I downloaded the deb but installation fails due to dependency.

```
$ sudo gdebi  ~/Downloads/firefox-esr_52.9.0esr+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Breaks existing package 'hunspell-en-us' that conflict: 'iceweasel'. But the '/home/user/Downloads/firefox-esr_52.9.0esr+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb' provides it via: 'gnome-www-browser,iceweasel,www-browser'
```

Comment: This is precisely why downgrading is not supported. You must downgrade not only the application itself, but many of the dependencies as well. You will become skilled at reading apt error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to remove Official Mozilla PPA with

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

and install package from [JonathonF PPA (`ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr-52`)](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr-52) with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr-52
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

As the result you will get Firefox ESR 52.9.0, but please note that you **will not get security updates as this version is obsolete**. The positive moment is that it is the last version supporting LEGACY ADDONS (for example I'm staying on this version to continue to use my addons such as SiteDelta, TableTools2, Show Parent Folder, Manage Folders, Wired Marker and others).