# How to tell the version of Firefox in Software Updater

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I am currently using Firefox 52esr (52.9.0). I want to keep using 52esr (I am aware of the issues in doing so and not asking about that here).

As of yesterday "Firefox Web Browser" is listed as an update item in Software Updater.

My question is how can I find out what version the update is before installing it.

In this case, the update could be a minor update within (52.9.0) (no problem) or update to the next esr which is/will be 60esr (not wanted). I don't know if it has been released by Ubuntu yet.

Also, is there any information whether 52esr will update to 60esr as routine (because 52esr support from Mozilla has ended)?

Comment: Firefox-esr is available through this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and it only has version 60.2.1. Version 52 is no longer supported.

Comment: What does `apt policy firefox` show?

Comment: I see. Thanks. My next question maybe also has a simple solution and not worthy of a new question. Is there a way to keep Firefox from appearing in Software Updates until I am ready to install it?

Comment: Are there release notes for 60.2.1? It is not listed in [Mozilla Firefox Release Notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/), even though 52.9.9 and other 52esr are.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1079090/66509 for the method of ESR 52 installation. But you take the risk as it is not supported anymore. But it supports LEGACY ADDONS - so I'll continue to use it.