# Install old version of firefox side by side with live default version

Tags: firefox

This question is highly related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770740/how-to-install-an-old-version-of-firefox-side-by-side-to-default-version-without) main question but with one key difference I just want to check:

I'd PREFER to have the old version use my profile, firefox sync, etc, to stay current with bookmarks AND i'm not bothered about having both open at the same time, the only reason I want it is because FF52 supports 2 old extensions which still haven't been updated to run quantum and I need them for a specific occasional task.

So: will I run into any problems just installing [FF52 for linux](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0/firefox-52.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2)? Or will it overwrite default current FF and/or cause other problems, does anyone know?

Edit: given I only really need the bookmarks to be synced, would it be better to create a separate profile then use a bookmark sync extension?

Thanks!

Edit2: re: possible duplicate: I'd argue that the main question is distinct from the question cited by N0rbert, so while one approach to solving my issue is shared with the other poster, there are alternative solutions to both of our questions. Conceptually this distinction strengthens the cause to leave this question up, as I suspect there will be a similar or greater number of people who want to run side-by-side than simply downgrade.

Comment: I'm writing this comment from ESR 52.9.0 on 16.04 LTS. It was installed from [JonathonF PPA as described in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079150/66509). Theoretically you can have both versions (Quantum for example may be unpacked to your home folder or as Snap).

Comment: Thanks Norbert. Indeed I already have that PPA's ESR general (which is now v60). I've now removed that PPA; do you know if I add the 52 PPA and update/install, will it overwrite ESR60 with ESR52? Also: please convert this to an answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: Edit: I tried that and it worked. Happy days, thanks!

Comment: Somewhat becomes a duplicate but largely on account of your extremely thorough answer to the other question covering a raft of situations which the question asker didn't explicitly cite.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the version in your question and then the newest version as a snap, that will guarantee you don't have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

There are some projects which are derived from Firefox such as waterfox etc..
Link: https://www.waterfoxproject.org/en-US/

You can run waterfox and Firefox parallelly.

Answer (score 1):

Bring up a terminal and run this command:

```
which firefox
```

now if you run this command:

```
ls -lisah "$(which firefox)"
```

you will see that your system actually uses a `symbolic link` pointing to the current version you have installed.

Now, if you install the newest version, this link will get updated, but you can make additional links to older installations that still reside on your hard drive.

The link can be used to create a `.desktop` file with additional META data that helps you choose the right version for your needs.

You can find out how to make `symlinks` and `.desktop` files by doing a search for these keywords.